# How can i find the corodinates of a point in python's "Turtle" library?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to make a shape using python's Turtle library and to do so, i have to find the corodinates of the center of my shape and then use the `goto()` command. Is this possible to do it?

And also I tried to reach the center with moving the turtle instead of using the `goto()` command but it is not possible or i am doing something wrong. Some help would be really apperciated!

Comment: Can you share your code? I'm confused: if you want to create a shape, it doesn't exist yet and you get to choose the center, right?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share your code?

1. If you are trying to find the current position of your turtle shape on screen use [turtle.pos()](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/turtle.html#turtle.pos)

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import random as rnd

screen = Screen()
my_shape = Turtle(shape='turtle')
my_shape.penup()
my_shape.goto(x=rnd.randint(1, 50), y=rnd.randint(1, 50))  # send turtle to random position ve+ x and ve+ y coordinate
curr_pos = my_shape.pos()  # get current turtle position by turtle.pos() method
print(f"current position: {curr_pos}")
screen.exitonclick()
```

output--> `current position: (45.00,5.00)`

2. If you are trying to bring back your shape in center screen use [turtle.home()](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/turtle.html#turtle.home)

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import random as rnd

screen = Screen()
my_shape = Turtle(shape='turtle')
my_shape.penup()
my_shape.goto(x=rnd.randint(1, 50), y=rnd.randint(1, 50))  # send turtle to random position ve+ x and ve+ y coordinate
curr_pos = my_shape.pos()  # get current turtle position by turtle.pos() method
print(f"current position: {curr_pos}")
my_shape.home()  # send turtle to home position (0,0)
home_pos = my_shape.pos()
print(f"Home position: {home_pos}")
screen.exitonclick()
```

output--> `current position: (48.00,41.00) Home position: (0.00,0.00)`